# Navigate to another view when async/await task finishes

Tags: swiftui, async-await

I'm pretty new to SwiftUI, so I'm wondering how to navigate to a new view only when an async method returns with a value.  Here is my view:

```
import SwiftUI

struct FollowersView: View {
    @State var followers: [Follower]
    @State var user: User?
    @State private var selection: String? = nil
    @StateObject private var viewModel = GitHubUsersViewModel()
    
    let columns = [
        GridItem(.flexible(minimum: 150, maximum: 175)),
        GridItem(.flexible(minimum: 150, maximum: 175)),
    ]
    
    var body: some View {
            ScrollView {
                LazyVGrid(columns: columns, spacing: 20) {
                        ForEach(followers, id: \.self) { follower in
                            FollowerCardView(follower: follower)
                                .onTapGesture {
                                    Task {
                                        self.user = try await self.viewModel.manager.getUser(for: follower.login)
                                        self.selection = NavigationTags.userFound
                                    }
                                }
                        }
                }
                .padding(.horizontal)
            }
        .frame(maxHeight: .infinity)
    }
}
```

When `self.user` gets populated, I want to be able to navigate to another view.  But, I can't figure out where to put the `NavigationLink`.

This `FollowersView` is already embedded in a `NavigationView` from within it's parent view.

Please advise?

Comment: What OS are you supporting? macOS? iOS 16? iOS 15?

Comment: I'm supporting iOS 15

Comment: You can use `.onChange(of: )` to listen for the change in `user` (when it gets populated)... I rarely use NavigationViews, so I'm not sure how to do the rest, but `.onChange(of:)` will let you perform a task once the value changes.

Comment: @stoic Tried it, doesn't seem to work.

Comment: You an hide the Lin behind something and use trigger `isActive`

Answer (score 0):

For iOS 15 you can still use `NavigationLink` as it isn't deprecated until iOS 16 when the new `NavigationStack` stuff comes in.

Anyway...

```
struct SomeView: View {
  @State var shouldNavigate: Bool = false

  var body: some View {
    NavigationLink(
      isActive: $shouldNavigate,
      destination: navDestination
    ) {
      Text("Press me")
        .onTapGesture {
          let result = await someAsyncFunction()
          shouldNavigate = true
        }
    }
  }

  @ViewBuilder
  var navDestination: some View {
    Text("Ta dah!")
  }
}
```

This will navigate to your destination when the async function completes and sets `shouldNavigate` to `true`.

There are nmany ways that you could do this. This is just one of them. Good luck

As a side note, you need to make sure your view is part of a `NavigationView` too.

Comment: This approach doesn't work.  If I use the following as navDestination, it says user is nil and crashes:

    @ViewBuilder
    var navDestination: some View {
        UserDetailView(user: self.user)
    }

Comment: Well yeah, if you need to put a user in there you will either need to pass the user into the view or store it somehow.

Comment: @JFortYork what is the unit method of the view you want to go to. You didn’t ask about any of that in the question so there was no way anyone could have known. I’ll update tomorrow. 

Answer (score 0):

I spent more time than I expected tracking this down, but for iOS 16+ the answer is somewhat trivial. All you need to do is provide a binding to the `.navigationDestination` call using a `NavigationStack`. Here is an example:

```
@State private var isTaskCompleted = false

 var body: some View {
    NavigationStack {
       ZStack {
         /// Somewhere within body you have an async task that flips the bound value

         Button(action: {
            Task.init(operation: {
                isTaskCompleted = await yourTask() // assuming yourTask() returns a Bool
            })
          }, label: {
              Text("Do Task")
          })
        }
        .navigationDestination(isPresented: $isTaskCompleted) {
           YourViewToNavigateToHere()
        }
     }
  }
```